# Xcode iOS build energy impact very high, mainly from overhead

Tags: ios, xcode

My app currently uses around 400mb of memory and the game is not complex, but my phone, an iPhone 12 pro max gets hot after around 10 minutes of playing the game. When I check the energy impact section, I see that theres a massive chunk that is overhead:
[image]

how should I go about fixing this issue? What exactly is the overhead caused by?

What I have tried so far:

1. Setting targetFPS to 60/30/-1, vsync to off/every other v blank, every v blank. These all produced the same result.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

instruments shows:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the overhead caused by?  Instruments will answer that question.

Comment: @matt hi matt, please check edited post. From instruments, it seems like network connections is generating the overhead? Which is expected, since i see that in the legend below the xcode panel it says that overhead is the work needed to maintain radio/wifi functionalities of the phone. My next question is, what is the Unknown connection listed in instruments?